# Multi-project sbt-assembly issues

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am trying to create a project with two main classes - SparkConsumer and KafkaProducer. For that, I have introduced multi-project structure in sbt file. Consumer and producer modules are for separate projects, core project holds utils which are used by both producer and consumer. Root is the main project. Common settings and libraries dependencies introduced too. However, for some reason, the project does not compile. All the sbt assemly related settigns are marked red. However, plugins.sbt with defined sbt-assembly plugin is in the root project.

What may be the solution for such a problem?

The project structure looks like this:

[image]

Here is build.sbt file:

```
lazy val overrides = Seq("com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.9.5",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.9.5",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.9.5")

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  name := "Demo",
  version := "0.1",
  scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
  resolvers += "Spark Packages Repo" at "http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven",
  dependencyOverrides += overrides
)

lazy val assemblySettings = Seq(
  assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
    case PathList("org","aopalliance", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("javax", "inject", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("javax", "activation", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("org", "apache", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("com", "google", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("com", "esotericsoftware", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("com", "codahale", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("com", "yammer", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("org", "slf4j", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("org", "neo4j", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("com", "typesafe", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("net", "jpountz", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case "about.html" => MergeStrategy.rename
    case "META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA" => MergeStrategy.last
    case "META-INF/mailcap" => MergeStrategy.last
    case "META-INF/mimetypes.default" => MergeStrategy.last
    case "plugin.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
    case "log4j.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
    case x =>
      val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
      oldStrategy(x)
  }
)

val sparkVersion = "2.2.0"

lazy val commonDependencies = Seq(
  "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "1.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % sparkVersion,
  "neo4j-contrib" % "neo4j-spark-connector" % "2.1.0-M4",
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0",
  "org.neo4j.driver" % "neo4j-java-driver" % "1.5.1",
  "com.opencsv" % "opencsv" % "4.1",
  "com.databricks" %% "spark-csv" % "1.5.0",
  "com.github.tototoshi" %% "scala-csv" % "1.3.5",
  "org.elasticsearch" %% "elasticsearch-spark-20" % "6.2.4"
)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    assemblySettings,
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies,
    assemblyJarName in assembly := "demo_root.jar"
  )
  .aggregate(core, consumer, producer)


lazy val core = project
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    assemblySettings,
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies
  )

lazy val consumer = project
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    assemblySettings,
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies,
    mainClass in assembly := Some("consumer.SparkConsumer"),
    assemblyJarName in assembly := "demo_consumer.jar"
  )
  .dependsOn(core)

lazy val producer = project
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    assemblySettings,
    libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies,
    mainClass in assembly := Some("producer.KafkaCheckinsProducer"),
    assemblyJarName in assembly := "demo_producer.jar"
  )
  .dependsOn(core)
```

UPDATE: Stack trace

```
(producer / update) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: a module is not authorized to depend on itself: demo#demo_2.11;0.1
[error] (consumer / update) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: a module is not authorized to depend on itself: demo#demo_2.11;0.1
[error] (core / Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-sql_2.12;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-streaming_2.12;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.databricks#spark-csv_2.12;1.5.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.elasticsearch#elasticsearch-spark-20_2.12;6.2.4: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.12;2.2.0: not found
```

Comment: can you update with the compilation error?

Answer (score 1):

> unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-sql_2.12;2.2.0

Spark 2.2.0 requires Scala 2.11, see https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/
For some reason scalaVersion from your commonSettings is not applied. You may need to set the global scalaVersion to work it around.

> Spark runs on Java 8+, Python 2.7+/3.4+ and R 3.1+. For the Scala API,
>   Spark 2.2.0 uses Scala 2.11. You will need to use a compatible Scala
>   version (2.11.x).

Also spark-sql and spark-streaming should be marked as "provided" as well